# WPF "object reference not set to an instance of an object" on client machine only

Tags: c#, wpf

I built a WPF application on my m/c and passed on the executable to a client. The application works perfectly well on my machine but throws an error on the client machine. My Logger picked up the following.

```
Message :Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source :App.Feeds
Stack Trace :   at App.Feeds.Port
<AdjustWeights>b__1(KeyValuePair`2 item) in
C:\App\1.0.1\App.Feeds\Port\IPort.cs:line 42
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum(IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 selector)
at App.Feeds.Port.Port.AdjustWeights() in
C:\App\1.0.1\App.Feeds\Port\IPort.cs:line 42
at App.Feeds.Port.Port.BuildPort(String 
fileName) in C:\App\1.0.1\App.Feeds\Port\IPort.cs:line 153
```

The strange thing I noticed is that the logger refers to a path `C:\App\1.0.1\App.Feeds\Port\IPort.cs` I use on the development machine. Is there something wrong with that?

What could be going wrong?

Comment: What object is on line 42 in IPort.cs?  How is it created?

Comment: I have a line with a `double` value that is assigned after a `foreach(var  item` of a dictionary. The dictionary is created with a `= new Dictionary<>`. Is it possible one of the values in the dictionary is null?

Comment: Post the code references in the stack trace from `IPort.cs`

Comment: I just found it. The dictionary had a null element and I was referencing it. Thanks all!

Comment: By the way it's normal to see those paths. If you have the PDB information, the stack trace will show line numbers and the full path of the source file on the machine it was built on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the Where clause is returning null and when you do a sum on that, it breaks.  May be you need to check if the result of the where clause has any items before you do the sum.